# how to call URL in axios.post request for get data each id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, axios

I'm fetching Data from an API using Axios and i'm displaying them as Cards in a Component movie cards, the thing is that i want to be able to click on a single movie card and the router take me to another page(singlepage.vue) with that movie id from the API and displaying the Book specific data but the problem is that I do not know how to send the ID of the same movie card I entered to the API and then return its data (I have to use the post method for request and put my post image below).
[this is postman image. click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2oES.jpg)

**firstPage.vue**
this is same component that i have movie cards.

```
<template>
   <div class="articles">
       <h2>featured articles</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="article-container">
       <div class="article-grid" v-for="data3 in datas3" :key="data3.ContentID" >
           <router-link to="/content"  >
           <img :src="data3.LandscapeImage">
           <div class="article-title">
               <p>{{data3.Properties[5].Value}}</p>
               <h3>{{data3.Title}}</h3>
           </div>
           </router-link>
       </div>
   </div>
   

    <div class="number-container">
               <a class="previous" href="">&laquo; <span>previous</span></a>
               <a href="">1</a>
               <a href="">2</a>
               <a href="">3</a>
               <a href="">4</a>
               <a href="">...</a>
               <a href="">10</a>
            <a class="next" href="#"> <span>next</span> &raquo;</a>
       </div>

</template>

<script>


export default {
name : "ThirdSection",
 props : ['datas3'],
   
} 
</script>
```

**singlepage.vue**
this is same component i want show data each cart after i click on card.

```
<template>

   <div class="content">
       <div class="content-sidebar">
       <SideBar />
       </div>
       <section class="main-content">

         <div class="content-container">
             <div class="content-img"> <img src="" alt=""></div>
             <div class="content-text" >
                 <h2></h2>
                 <p></p>
             </div>
         </div>
       </section>
    
   </div>


</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

import SideBar from '../../components/Sidebar.vue'

export default {
components :{
    SideBar
},

//I have a problem here//
setup() {
   const request = { RequestID : "16460"}
    function getContent (){
  axios.post('request url', request ,
  { headers : {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      }}
  )
  
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}
 getContent();
 return {};
    }
   
}
</script>
```

Comment: see where you `console.log(response);` ... that's where you have the response to do with as you need

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to create a route for the single page that has params in it, and parse them in the component to use them in the request.

See: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Register your routes with the desired component and specify a parameter:

```
{ path: '/user/:book_id', component: require("<singlepage.vue>"), props: true }
```

singlepage.vue:

```
<template>

   <div class="content">
       <div class="content-sidebar">
       <SideBar />
       </div>
       <section class="main-content">

         <div class="content-container">
             <div class="content-img"> <img src="" alt=""></div>
             <div class="content-text" >
                 <h2></h2>
                 <p></p>
             </div>
         </div>
       </section>
    
   </div>


</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

import SideBar from '../../components/Sidebar.vue'

export default {
components :{
    SideBar
},
props: ["book_id"],
//I have a problem here//
setup() {
   const request = { RequestID : "16460"}
    function getContent (){
  axios.post('request url', request ,
  { headers : {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      }}
  )
  
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}
 getContent();
 return {};
    }
   
}
</script>
```

Comment: how to add const user in component? please help me:)

Comment: that was just an example, in your case `singlepage.vue` should expect the prop to use for the request

Comment: @fgkh were you able to solve it?